# Can I use jquery keyup functions on mediaelement.js controls

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

**I have created an audio playlist using mediaelement.js  I use most of my own controls such as volume control, loop play/pause and forward/rewind and I have all these controls on jquery keyup events. I can use the mediaelement.js click event to go to previous track, next track and toggle shuffle, but I do not know where this code exists in the mediaelement.js file  or how it works. Is there a way to control the go to next track or previous track or to toggle shuffle with a keyup event?. For example, to control volume:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){

if(e.keyCode ===38){//the up arrow


var volume = $(audio).prop("volume")+0.1;

if(volume >1){
    volume = 1;
}
$(audio).prop("volume",volume);

}


});
```

is there some way I could use the keyup function to go to the previous or next tracks and to toggle shuffle?
Any help or insight will be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

**I was trying everything and figured it out. In the mep-feature-playlist.js, under the PREVIOUS TRACK BUTTON comment and then under the .click(function(e)...add this code:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 188){//< or , key
            $(media).trigger('mep-playprevtrack');
      player.playPrevTrack();

        }

    });
```

Press the < or key will go to the previous track. The same thing can be done for the next track under the // NEXT TRACK BUTTON comment.**